# Make sidebar collapsible

Tags: feature-request

Can we make the sidebar collapsible, as a regular visitor I already know everything the sidebar has to offer I don’t need it to be shown to me on every other page I visit.

[image]

[image]

By collapsible sidebar I mean something similar to what you have in [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/09/13/unveiling-gitlabs-new-navigation)

Comment: Go to your user profile -> go to the Settings tab on top -> go to Preferences and Site Settings -> in the Navigation section tick the "Hide left navigation" https://i.imgur.com/XYvroz3.png